# Does list initialization initialize atomics to zero?

Tags: c++, initialization, atomic

**Question:**

Does `std::atomic<int> a{};` initialize `a` (to zero) or not?

**Background:**

Usually, I expect that `T a{};` either gives a compile-time error or makes sure that `a` is initilized and ready to use. Either because `T` is a fundamental/POD-like type and the language rules about aggregate/zero/value/list initialization result in everything being initialized to zero (I lost track of what is what exactly) or because the default constructor is called which "usually" brings the object into a usable state. 
Sure, classes that require (not just allow) double initialization exist but seem to be rather rare - particularly in the standard library.

However, the documentation for the constructor of  [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) says

> 1) The default constructor is trivial: no initialization takes place other than zero initialization of static and thread-local objects. std::atomic_init may be used to complete initialization.
>
> [...]
>
> The default-initialized std::atomic does not contain a T object, and its only valid uses are destruction and initialization by std::atomic_init, see [LWG 2334](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2334)

Which I read that this

```
std::atomic<int> a{};
assert(a.load() == 0);
```

is not just not guaranteed but actually undefined behavior.

If that is the case, then it is imho a major pitfall for usage of atomics, in particular because it seems to be one of the UB cases that work "as expected" on most platforms: https://godbolt.org/g/DmEGDE

**EDIT:** Also I don't quite understand, why this "ensures compatibility with C" what harm would it do to just guarantee that all the bits are set to zero?

**Note:** 
I know that I can just write `std::atomic<int> a{0}`

Comment: I think you're right that according to the standard the value is not initialized, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `std::atomic<int> a{};` initializes `a` to zero.

This syntax starts a *value-initialization* of `std::atomic<int>`, which in turns runs a zero-initialization<sup>1</sup>. This means, even though `std::atomic<int>` has a default constructor<sup>2</sup>, it is not called<sup>3</sup> and all members of `a` are zero-initialized.

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> #### [`[dcl.init]/8.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8.2)
>
> 8) To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> 8.2) if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if `T` has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

<sup>2)</sup>

> #### [`[atomics.types.operations]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.generic#atomics.types.operations-2)
>
> ```
>  atomic() noexcept = default;
> ```
>
> Effects: Leaves the atomic object in an uninitialized state. [ Note: These semantics ensure compatibility with C. — end note ]

<sup>3)</sup>

> #### [`[dcl.fct.def.default]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#5.sentence-2)
>
> A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.

Comment: Not sure if I should love or hate c++ for that.

Comment: Actually, is it even guaranteed that an `std::atomic<T>` has a member of type `T`?

Comment: @MikeMB that's the question I was asking myself, but I'm stuck commuting right now.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @MikeMB No it is not mandatory. But this is [strongly](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.generic#atomics.types.operations-8) [suggested](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.generic#3). [For integer types, `atomic` is a standard-layout](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.generic#atomics.types.int-2) **and** `this` points to a _value_ semantically equivalent to an integer of the same type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is good enough for me then - I don't really work with completely exotic hardware or compilers

Comment: EDIT: Args - stale cache in my browser. Here is the link again: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0883r0.pdf

Comment: Doesn't the claim in this answer, that std::atomic<int> a{}; initializes a to zero, directly contradict what is said in P0883R0, which asys "std::atomic<int> x{};
// does NOT zero initialize"?

Comment: @Eric I think my answer is completely incorrect. I need to get back on a desktop computer and re-read all that happened to atomic since my answer, 3 and a half years ago.